# Как вернуть подстроку из записи в mySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Мне нужно выбрать из базы данных, из одной ячейки не весь текст а только подстроку. Существует ли запрос SQL, похожий на функцию php - substr()? Или какой-то другой способ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь с функциями обработки строк в [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

[SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) , [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Answer (score 4):

Конечно, cуществует - [substr()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) - синоним [substring()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).

Comment: я имею в виду в SQL типа SELECT SUBSTR...

Comment: Т.е. select substring не нравится, надо select substr?

Comment: А в чем проблема? `select substr(`fulltext`, 0, 200) as announce from `posts` order by `id` desc limit 0, 10`

Comment: вот это нравится